# How to use pandas.DataFrame.to_sql with multiple databases using SQLALCHEMY_BINDS

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have declared 2 databases:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI ='postgresql://dbuser:dbpassword@localhost:5432/dbname1'
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'dbname2':        'postgresql://dbuser2:dbpassword2@localhost:5432/dbname2',

}
```

i declared:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

now I create different type of data frame from csv uploads, manipulate them using some values found in tables within the dbname1 database. Then I want to save the resulting df into tables within the database dbname2 to give access to my clients (separate the access from dbname1 that contains sensitive info).

any idea how to use the pandas.DataFrame.to_sql function to redirect to database dbname2?

Thank you